# Why transaction with 'readOnly' save record

Tags: java, transactions

I have method:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Person> getPersonList(Form form) {
    return personDao.listCustom(form);
}
```

personDao is intercept with PersonInceptor. This interceptor saving request:

```
public Odpoved logRequest(Request request) {
    return requestDao.insert(request);
}
```

My question is why this example is working and do not throw exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readOnly=true` is a hint to the ORM framework in order to optimize data access, not an impediment for writing. You can read it from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html

> readOnly
>
> public abstract boolean readOnly true if the transaction is read-only.
>   Defaults to false. **This just serves as a hint for the actual
>   transaction subsystem; it will not necessarily cause failure of write
>   access attempts**. A transaction manager which cannot interpret the
>   read-only hint will not throw an exception when asked for a read-only
>   transaction.
>
> See Also: TransactionDefinition.isReadOnly() Default: false